# How to check the concavity of the following formula

Tags: convex-optimization

I have a formula containing two squared root components as follows:

$1 - \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{\forall i \in \mathcal{I}}\sum_{\forall j \in \mathcal{J}}(a_{ij} - b_{ij})^2}}{\sqrt{\sum_{\forall i \in \mathcal{I}}\sum_{\forall j \in \mathcal{J}}a_{ij}^2}}$.

Assume that $a_{ij}, \forall i \in \mathcal{I}, \forall j \in \mathcal{J}$ are constants. How to know that the above equation is concave or convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can view it as $$1-\frac1u \|A-B\|_F$$ where $u$ is a positive constant.

since we know that the frobenius norm is convex, multiplying by a negative number makes it concave. Shifting it by $1$ doesn't change the property.

Hence it is a concave function.

Comment: So is $u$ the same as $\sqrt{\sum_{\forall i \in \mathcal{I}}\sum_{\forall j \in \mathcal{J}}a_{ij}^2}$? I forget that the denominator is also the Frobenius norm but also constant.

Comment: yes, we are told that it is a constant.

Comment: Could you help me to answer the edited formula in the above question? Thank you.

Comment: seems to be true from triangle inequality.

Comment: Do you mean because $1 - \frac{\bigg\|\mathbf{a} - \frac{\sum_{m=1}^M m(x_{m} - x_{m-1})}{\gamma} \mathbf{b}\bigg\|_F}{\|\mathbf{a}\|_F} = 1 - \frac{\|\mathbf{a}\|_F - \frac{\sum_{m=1}^M m(x_{m} - x_{m-1})}{\gamma} \|\mathbf{b}\|_F}{\|\mathbf{a}\|_F}$?

Comment: I mean we can prove it from the definition.  During the proof, we can use the triangle inequality to prove concavity.